# Get every Nth result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this large set of data and I want a sample that I can use in a graph. For this I don't need all of the data, I need every Nth item.

For instance if I have 4000 results, and I only need 800 results, I want to be able to get every 5th result.

So some like: get, skip, skip, skip, skip, get, skip, skip, skip,..

I was wondering if such a thing is possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off using a scripted `filter`. Otherwise you're needlessly using the score. Filters are just like queries, but they don't use scoring.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['unique_counter'].value % n == 0",
          "params" : {
            "n" : 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You're also better off not using dynamic scripting in real world usage.

That said, you probably want to take a look at aggregations for graphing analytical information about your data rather than taking an arbitrary sample.

Comment: Thanks, how do I go about creating a "unique_counter" property?

Comment: `unique_counter` is up to you. There's nothing in the scripts that tells you what the document number is. If your `_id` is numeric/sequential, then you can use that for this purpose. Otherwise you need to come store something to represent count. Again though, the best option here is to look at aggregations rather than doing this.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is with [random scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html). It won't give you precisely every nth item according to a rigid ordering, but if you can relax that requirement this trick should do nicely.

To test it I set up a simple index (I mapped `"doc_id"` to `"_id"` just so the documents would have some contents, so that part isn't required, in case that's not obvious):

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_id": {
            "path": "doc_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I indexed ten simple documents:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":1}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":2}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":3}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":4}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":5}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":6}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":7}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":8}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":9}
{"index":{}}
{"doc_id":10}
```

Now I can pull back three random documents like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 3,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "random_score": {
                  "seed": "some seed"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0.93746644,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.93746644,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "10",
            "_score": 0.926947,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 10
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.79400194,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 5
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Or a different random three like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 3,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "random_score": {
                  "seed": "some other seed"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0.817295,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.817295,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 4
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "8",
            "_score": 0.469319,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 8
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.4374538,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 3
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hopefully it's clear how to generalize this method to what you need. Just take out however many documents you want, in however many chunks make it performant.

Here is all the code I used to test:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a02d4da458365915f5e9cf6ea80546d2dfabc75d

**EDIT:** Actually now that I think about it, you could also use [scripted scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) to get precisely every nth item, if you set it up right. Maybe something like,

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 3,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "if(doc['doc_id'].value % 3 == 0){ return 1 }; return 0;"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 13,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 3
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 6
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "9",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "doc_id": 9
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the other answer is probably better than mine, for most purposes.

Comment: This still requires doc_id to be available; _id is not accessible here, and _uid requires string manipulation to extract the _id